# Razor foreach loop loses item property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a dynamic radio button group based on a selectlist within my model. when I pass a model to the View I want it to have the radio button selected based on the selected property of the selectlist.
Here is what I have in the View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RadioGroup)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RadioSelection, item.Value, new { @checked = item.Selected })
    <label class="control-label">@item.Text</label>
}
```

Every time I navigate to the page the last radio button is selected no matter what the property is set to in the controller.

I have set a breakpoint in the view, the `Model.RadioGroup` list has all of the radio buttons correct with the correct one having its selected property to true but when that item comes up in the loop and gets transferred to the `item` object the `item` gains all other properties (value and text) but sets the `selected` property to `false`.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong or how to map the selected property to the item for use in the loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your use of `new { @checked = item.Selected }` means that your setting the `checked` property. `checked="checked"` or `checked="true"` or `checked="anyValueWhatSoEver"` all result in setting the `checked` attribute (although only the first one is valid html).

As a result, as the DOM is loaded, the `checked` property of the first radio button is set. In the next iteration, the `checked` property of the second one is set (and removed from the first because only one radio button in a group can be `checked`).

Since you using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` to bind to the property `RadioSelection`, you need to set the value of `RadioSelection` in the controller before you pass the model to the view. If the value matches one of your items, then that button will be selected (and remove `new { @checked = item.Selected }` from the helper).

Side note: You should also consider giving the radio buttons a unique `id` attribute and use `<label for="theID" ..>` (or just wrapping the helper in a `<label>` element so it acts as a label (i.e. clicking on it sets focus to the associated radio button) - currently is does nothing and really should just be a `<span>` element

Comment: Ah, ok.. I thought you could just set checked to true or false for all in the group and only the true one got 'checked' thanks ill try that and update accordingly

Comment: That worked. thanks. and thanks for the tip with the `<label>` I have added that into the solution as well.